# Как получить сумму всех чисел в списке?

Tags: python

Как получить сумму чисел в списке?

Список состоит из чисел в виде `str`, с плавающей точкой.
Конвертировал список из `str` в `int`, тогда можно применить `sum()`, но все числа округляются, это не подходит, падает точность расчетов.

Что было сделано?

```
some_list = ['0.11', '0.09', '1.0', '0.5', '0.33', '0.25', '0.2', '0.2', '0.16', '0.14', '0.07', '0.03', '0.01', '1.81']

res = [int(itm) for itm in some_list]   
res2 = list(map(int, some_list))
```

Как преобразовать список в числа и получить их сумму, как одну запись в списке?

Пример:

```
some_list = [24.25]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно конвертировать не в int, а в float, хотя операции с плавающей точкой могут быть не очень точными и это надо иметь ввиду.

```
math.fsum(list(map(float, some_list)))
```

Для более точных расчетов можно поискать библиотеки, к примеру какой-нибудь bigfloat https://pypi.org/project/bigfloat/.

Comment: можно использовать `Decimal`

Comment: @Danis, можно, если автор вопроса решит принять другой ответ вместо моего, я не против.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, конечно, напрашиваеся использование стандартной библиотеки `decimal`. В ней десятичные числа могут быть представлены точно, как в школе. И эти числа хорошо взаимодействуют с большей частью Python.
Поэтому код получается таким:

```
import decimal as d

some_list = ['0.11', '0.09', '1.0', '0.5', '0.33', '0.25',
             '0.2', '0.2', '0.16', '0.14', '0.07', '0.03', '0.01', '1.81']

print(sum(list(map(d.Decimal, some_list))))
```

Сначала преобразуем список строк в список десятичных "цифр" и затем суммируем. Получаем точный результат.